# JavaScript/HTML -- Variable SetTimeout syntax

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a basic game. As my code shows below, if the jumping variable is set to false and the space bar is pressed, then an object moves up (and, thus, jumps).

This works. However, I don't want the object to jump indefinitely. So, very crudely, I am setting a timeout so that after 2 seconds, the jumping variable again = false, and so jumping can again occur.

I realize this is very crude; however, this is how I would like to program it. After adding the last two lines

`(jumping = true and setTimeout(function () { jumping == false; }, 2000);)` the object no longer jumps. I believe i have the setTimeout function not written correctly despite no errors existing. Can anyone shed any light?

I apologize if this is a silly question, and excuse my awful crude coding.

---

```
            //function to handle keyboard events
            function KeyboardEventHandler(event) {
                //if the up arrow is pressed
                if (jumping == false && event.keyCode == keycode.SPACE) {
                    object.VY -= 0.1;
                    jumping = true;
                    setTimeout(function () { jumping == false; }, 2000);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Should be jumping = false, not jumping == false within the setTimeout.